# シェルスクリプト内での解凍コマンドの実行権限について

Tags: macos, shellscript

unxzコマンドを.sh file内から実行する際に、permission diniedエラー(以下)が表示されコマンドを実行できない。

```
unxz: /Users/＊＊＊/mecab-ipadic-neologd/libexec/../build/mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801-neologd-20190826/mecab-user-dict-seed.20190826.csv.xz: Permission denied
```

補足として直接そのxzファイルにterminalからunxzコマンドを実行した際は、問題なく解凍された。

### やったこと

- shファイルとxzファイル両方の権限を777にしての実行
- sudoコマンドでの実行
- rootユーザに切り替えての実行

### 実行環境

macOS Mojave 10.14.6
コマンドシェル：zsh

### log

```
> ./bin/install-mecab-ipadic-neologd -n -a
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Start..
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Check the existance of libraries
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     find => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     sort => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     head => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     cut => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     egrep => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     mecab => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     mecab-config => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     make => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     curl => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     sed => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     cat => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     diff => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     tar => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     unxz => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     xargs => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     grep => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     iconv => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     patch => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     which => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     file => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     openssl => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     awk => ok

[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : mecab-ipadic-NEologd is already up-to-date

[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : mecab-ipadic-NEologd will be install to /usr/local/lib/mecab/dic/mecab-ipadic-neologd

[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Make mecab-ipadic-NEologd
[make-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Start..
[make-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Check local seed directory
[make-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Check local seed file
[make-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Check local build directory
[make-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : create /Users/***/mecab-ipadic-neologd/libexec/../build
[make-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Download original mecab-ipadic file
[make-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Try to access to https://ja.osdn.net
[make-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Try to download from https://ja.osdn.net/frs/g_redir.php?m=kent&f=mecab%2Fmecab-ipadic%2F2.7.0-20070801%2Fmecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 11.6M  100 11.6M    0     0  10.0M      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 21.9M
Hash value of /Users/***/mecab-ipadic-neologd/libexec/../build/mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801.tar.gz matched
[make-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Decompress original mecab-ipadic file
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/README
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/AUTHORS
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/COPYING
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/ChangeLog
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/INSTALL
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Makefile.am
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Makefile.in
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/NEWS
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/aclocal.m4
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/config.guess
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/config.sub
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/configure
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/configure.in
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/install-sh
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/missing
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/mkinstalldirs
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Adj.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Adnominal.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Adverb.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Auxil.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Conjunction.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Filler.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Interjection.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Noun.adjv.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Noun.adverbal.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Noun.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Noun.demonst.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Noun.nai.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Noun.name.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Noun.number.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Noun.org.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Noun.others.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Noun.place.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Noun.proper.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Noun.verbal.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Others.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Postp-col.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Postp.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Prefix.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Suffix.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Symbol.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/Verb.csv
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/char.def
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/feature.def
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/left-id.def
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/matrix.def
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/pos-id.def
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/rewrite.def
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/right-id.def
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/unk.def
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/dicrc
x mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801/RESULT
[make-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Configure custom system dictionary on /Users/***/mecab-ipadic-neologd/libexec/../build/mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801-neologd-20190826
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for working aclocal-1.4... missing
checking for working autoconf... found
checking for working automake-1.4... missing
checking for working autoheader... found
checking for working makeinfo... found
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for mecab-config... /usr/local/bin/mecab-config
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
[make-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Encode the character encoding of system dictionary resources from EUC_JP to UTF-8
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Noun.place.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Auxil.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Noun.verbal.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Symbol.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Noun.org.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Noun.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Postp.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Adj.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Filler.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Noun.proper.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Noun.number.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Suffix.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Noun.others.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Interjection.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Noun.adjv.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Verb.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Others.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Adnominal.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Prefix.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Noun.demonst.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Adverb.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Noun.name.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Postp-col.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Conjunction.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Noun.nai.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./Noun.adverbal.csv
rm ./Noun.place.csv
rm ./Auxil.csv
rm ./Noun.verbal.csv
rm ./Symbol.csv
rm ./Noun.org.csv
rm ./Noun.csv
rm ./Postp.csv
rm ./Adj.csv
rm ./Filler.csv
rm ./Noun.proper.csv
rm ./Noun.number.csv
rm ./Suffix.csv
rm ./Noun.others.csv
rm ./Interjection.csv
rm ./Noun.adjv.csv
rm ./Verb.csv
rm ./Others.csv
rm ./Adnominal.csv
rm ./Prefix.csv
rm ./Noun.demonst.csv
rm ./Adverb.csv
rm ./Noun.name.csv
rm ./Postp-col.csv
rm ./Conjunction.csv
rm ./Noun.nai.csv
rm ./Noun.adverbal.csv
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./rewrite.def
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./matrix.def
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./left-id.def
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./pos-id.def
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./unk.def
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./feature.def
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./right-id.def
./../../libexec/iconv_euc_to_utf8.sh ./char.def
rm ./rewrite.def
rm ./matrix.def
rm ./left-id.def
rm ./pos-id.def
rm ./unk.def
rm ./feature.def
rm ./right-id.def
rm ./char.def
mv ./Noun.others.csv.utf8 ./Noun.others.csv
mv ./Noun.number.csv.utf8 ./Noun.number.csv
mv ./Filler.csv.utf8 ./Filler.csv
mv ./Others.csv.utf8 ./Others.csv
mv ./unk.def.utf8 ./unk.def
mv ./Postp-col.csv.utf8 ./Postp-col.csv
mv ./Adnominal.csv.utf8 ./Adnominal.csv
mv ./Noun.verbal.csv.utf8 ./Noun.verbal.csv
mv ./matrix.def.utf8 ./matrix.def
mv ./Noun.csv.utf8 ./Noun.csv
mv ./Noun.demonst.csv.utf8 ./Noun.demonst.csv
mv ./char.def.utf8 ./char.def
mv ./Symbol.csv.utf8 ./Symbol.csv
mv ./Auxil.csv.utf8 ./Auxil.csv
mv ./Noun.name.csv.utf8 ./Noun.name.csv
mv ./feature.def.utf8 ./feature.def
mv ./Suffix.csv.utf8 ./Suffix.csv
mv ./Adverb.csv.utf8 ./Adverb.csv
mv ./Conjunction.csv.utf8 ./Conjunction.csv
mv ./pos-id.def.utf8 ./pos-id.def
mv ./Postp.csv.utf8 ./Postp.csv
mv ./right-id.def.utf8 ./right-id.def
mv ./Noun.nai.csv.utf8 ./Noun.nai.csv
mv ./Interjection.csv.utf8 ./Interjection.csv
mv ./Prefix.csv.utf8 ./Prefix.csv
mv ./Noun.place.csv.utf8 ./Noun.place.csv
mv ./Noun.adjv.csv.utf8 ./Noun.adjv.csv
mv ./rewrite.def.utf8 ./rewrite.def
mv ./Verb.csv.utf8 ./Verb.csv
mv ./left-id.def.utf8 ./left-id.def
mv ./Noun.proper.csv.utf8 ./Noun.proper.csv
mv ./Adj.csv.utf8 ./Adj.csv
mv ./Noun.adverbal.csv.utf8 ./Noun.adverbal.csv
mv ./Noun.org.csv.utf8 ./Noun.org.csv
[make-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Fix yomigana field of IPA dictionary
patching file Noun.csv
patching file Noun.place.csv
patching file Verb.csv
patching file Noun.verbal.csv
patching file Noun.name.csv
patching file Noun.adverbal.csv
patching file Noun.csv
patching file Noun.name.csv
patching file Noun.org.csv
patching file Noun.others.csv
patching file Noun.place.csv
patching file Noun.proper.csv
patching file Noun.verbal.csv
patching file Prefix.csv
patching file Suffix.csv
patching file Noun.proper.csv
patching file Noun.csv
patching file Noun.name.csv
patching file Noun.org.csv
patching file Noun.place.csv
patching file Noun.proper.csv
patching file Noun.verbal.csv
patching file Noun.name.csv
patching file Noun.org.csv
patching file Noun.place.csv
patching file Noun.proper.csv
patching file Suffix.csv
patching file Noun.demonst.csv
patching file Noun.csv
patching file Noun.name.csv
[make-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Copy user dictionary resource
unxz: /Users/***/mecab-ipadic-neologd/libexec/../build/mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801-neologd-20190826/mecab-user-dict-seed.20190826.csv.xz: Permission denied
```

### 実行コマンド

```
./bin/install-mecab-ipadic-neologd -n -a
```

(-a抜きで実行したら、mkdirのコマンドの権限がないということでpermission deniedがでました)
やはりシェルスクリプト内で実行されるコマンドに権限がないようです。

## 追記

```
$ ./bin/install-mecab-ipadic-neologd -n -a
```

<s>実行時に、毎度onlineでファイルを取得するようで、その前にディレクトリの権限を再帰的に変更したとしても新たなファイルでは書き込み権限なしで保存されているため、permission error がおこるようです。。</s>

と思いましたが、解凍したいファイル'mecab-user-dict-seed.20190826.csv.xz'の作成時の権限は

```
-rw-r--r--
```

であり、このままユーザ権限でunxzコマンドが実行できたので、解凍したいファイルの権限は関係ないように思われます。
また、unxzを行うshファイルの権限を777に変更しても、結果は同じでした。

sh file は[こちら](https://github.com/neologd/mecab-ipadic-neologd)で参照できるため、error logを記載することにしました。

- set -x 追加後

```
[make-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Copy user dictionary resource
+ SEED_FILE_NAME=mecab-user-dict-seed.20190826.csv
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ cp /Users/***/mecab-ipadic-neologd/libexec/../seed/mecab-user-dict-seed.20190826.csv.xz /Users/***/mecab-ipadic-neologd/libexec/../build/mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801-neologd-20190826
+ unxz /Users/***/mecab-ipadic-neologd/libexec/../build/mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801-neologd-20190826/mecab-user-dict-seed.20190826.csv.xz
unxz: /Users/***/mecab-ipadic-neologd/libexec/../build/mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801-neologd-20190826/mecab-user-dict-seed.20190826.csv.xz: Permission denied
```

Comment: その `.sh file` の内容を記載して頂けると回答が得られやすくなるかもしれません。

Comment: ファイルの保存場所(ディレクトリ)自体のパーミッションも関連してくるかと思います。書き込み権限の無いディレクトリに対して解凍しようとしている等。

Comment: @cubick 
dir全体にchmod -R 777 [dirname]をしましたが、変化はありませんでした

Comment: インストールしようとしているのは [mecab-ipadic-neologd](https://github.com/neologd/mecab-ipadic-neologd)で、"How to install/update mecab-ipadic-NEologd" に書かれている通りに実行しているという事でよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: @metropolis はい。その通りです。

Comment: スクリプトに`set -x`を足して実行してみてはどうでしょう。気になったのはmvやrmされることがあると思いますが、そのあたりも問題ないかです。

Comment: この質問に貼られたスクリプトと、[GitHubで公開されているもの](https://github.com/neologd/mecab-ipadic-neologd/blob/master/bin/install-mecab-ipadic-neologd) とではかなり差があるように見えます。

Comment: 「直接そのxzファイルにterminalからunxzコマンドを実行」とは、`unxz /Users/＊＊＊/mecab-ipadic-neologd/libexec/../build/mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801-neologd-20190826/mecab-user-dict-seed.20190826.csv.xz` を実行したということですか? (xz ファイルをフルパスで指定)

Comment: 掲示されているシェルスクリプトは[こちら](https://github.com/neologd/mecab-ipadic-neologd/blob/master/libexec/make-mecab-ipadic-neologd.sh)で、`bin/install-mecab-ipadic-neologd` の内部から実行されます。

Comment: @cubick 紛らわしくてすみません。質問に貼ったスクリプトはerrorが出たshファイルのlibexec/mecab-ipadic-neologd.shについて記載しました。

Comment: @fumiyas はい。そうです。

Comment: @metropolis 補足ありがとうございます

Comment: @fliedonion set -xを足して実行した結果の最後の部分を記載しました
mvやrmはlogからみるに、問題なく実行されているようです。

Comment: MojaveではデフォルトでSIPが有効になっているんで、多くのUnix用インストールスクリプトが失敗します。SIPを無効化するのは試してみましたか?

Comment: @OOPer はい。今回の試行以前からSIPは無効になっています。

Comment: 「直接そのxzファイルにterminalからunxzコマンドを実行した際は、問題なく解凍された。」との事ですが、ログインシェルは zsh ですよね。これを bash で実行するとどうなりますか？ `bash -c 'unxz .../mecab-user-dict-seed.20190826.csv.xz'`

Comment: @metropolis そちらのコマンドでは実行できなかったので、```chsh -s /bin/bash```でログインシェルをbashに戻してからunxzコマンドを対象ファイルに実行しましたが、問題なく解凍されました。ログインシェルの違いよるものではないようです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

試行錯誤の結果、根本的な原因は不明ですが対応することができました。
以下に、行った処理を記しておきます。

仕組みとして、インストール(アップデート)時に毎度(必要があれば)更新ファイルをダウンロードし、それらを一時的に保管します。
その後、それらをbase dirにcp→unxz(解凍)という順番だったのですが、それをunxz→cpという順番にする(sh fileを書き換える)ことで解決しました。

おそらく、 cp後のdirのパスがなにか悪影響を与えていたのだと考えられます。